Implementation of the parameters error in the Matlab program
I have this Matlab code that create a sinusoidal fit from a set of data
data = importdata('analisipicco.txt') ;  
x = data(:,1) ; y = data(:,2) ; 
yu = max(y);
yl = min(y);
yr = (yu-yl);                               % Range of ‘y’
yz = y-yu+(yr/2);
zx = x(yz .* circshift(yz,1) <= 0);     % Find zero-crossings
per = 2*mean(diff(zx));                     % Estimate period
ym = mean(y);                               % Estimate offset

fit = @(b,x)  b(1).*(sin(2*pi*x./b(2) + 2*pi/b(3))) + b(4);    % Function to fit
fcn = @(b) sum((fit(b,x) - y).^2);                              % Least-Squares cost function
s = fminsearch(fcn, [yr;  per;  -1;  ym]);                      % Minimise Least-Squares

xp = linspace(min(x),max(x));

xlabel("passi motore");
ylabel("intensità (u.a.)");
figure(1)
plot(x,y,'o',  xp,fit(s,xp), 'r')
grid

Where the elements of output parameter vector, s ( b in the function ) are:
s(1): sine wave amplitude (in units of y)
s(2): period (in units of x)
s(3): phase (phase is s(2)/(2*s(3)) in units of x)
s(4): offset (in units of y)
For acknowledge this is my data set:
-200 183966
-192 189734
-184 195724
-176 201663
-168 207557
-160 213278
-152 219000
-144 224677
-136 229500
-128 236024
-120 241968
-112 247787
-104 252963
-96 257491
-88 261967
-80 267373
-72 273494
-64 278599
-56 281476
-48 282610
-40 283097
-32 283839
-24 284971
-16 286169
-8  287164
0   287968
8   288561
16  288626
24  288107
32  286967
40  285132
48  282828
56  279847
64  276296
72  272299
80  268080
88  263564
96  258926
104 254052
112 248894
120 243694
128 238177
136 232665
144 227143
152 221959
160 216874
168 211678
176 206540
184 201537
192 196748
200 192091

The program works out fine, but my question is about finding the errors on the parameters and the covariance as well, I could implement the matrix method and finding the covariance matrix but I don't know how to write as a code.
I'm new to Matlab so I want to ask if there was some function that calculate the errors as well.
Thank you in advance :))

Yes, there is a function specifically for Least-Squares method. It is called lsqcurvefit 3-rd output argument gives the residuals (errors) you want. See
help lsqcurvefit

In your case
initial_guess = [yr; per; -1; ym];
[s, resnorm, residual] = lsqcurvefit(fit, initial_guess, x, y);
plot(x, residual)

For the covariance I didn't find any method other then to compute it from the Jacobian (which is the 7th output arguments of lsqcurvefit):
[s, resnorm, residual, flag, output, lambda, jacobian] = lsqcurvefit(fit, initial_guess, x, y);
covariance = inv(jacobian' * jacobian) * resnorm / (length(y) - length(s));

Please check that this covariance formula is the one you want to compute.
I hope this answers well.

Very nice answer, I wonder how would this look like in comparison with a code I wrote for error propagation in python. Might check it out and post a question in case something does not check out :D
